# Cosine Similarity: I would like to understand the values I get

Tags: r, text-mining, cosine-similarity, doc2vec

I am currently trying to use word embeddings and cosine simarity in order to determine the similarity of two documents written in german.

```
Example Data:
Document_A <- "Ich gehe heute einkaufen" ##(English: I am going shopping today) 
Document_B <- "Das Wetter ist heute gut" ##(English: The weather today is good)
```

I tokenized and lemmatized the Documents and so forth using the following:

```
tkn <- function(SelectedGroup){ 
  ## Lemmatization
  abc <- lemmatize_strings(SelectedGroup, dictionary = lemma_data)
  ## Delete Punctuation etc.
  abc <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", abc[1])
  ## Transform everything to lower case letters
  abc <- tolower(abc)
  ## Elimination of stopwords
  abc <- tm::removeWords(tm::scan_tokenizer(abc), mystopwords)
}

treatment_tkn <- tkn(Document_A)
control_tkn <- tkn(Document_B)
```

In order to compare both documents I used:

```
word_embedding <- "C:/Users/Aaron/Desktop/Testordner/embeddings_german.txt" 
 ## This file has been downloaded on http://vectors.nlpl.eu/repository/#. (Language german, ID=45)
 ## It has the following properties: Vector size: 100, Window: 10, Corpus: German CoNLL17 corpus,Vocabulary size: 4946997,Algorithm: Word2Vec Continuous Skipgram, Lemmatization: False

 ## apply the word embeddings vectors on the treatment and control variable
token_list <- list(treatment_tkn,control_tkn)
init <- Doc2Vec$new(token_list = token_list, word_vector_FILE = word_embedding)
out = init$doc2vec_methods(method = "sum_sqrt")
 ## Calculate the cosine similarity of the two groups (measures the angle between the two vectors)
Cosine_similarity <- cosine(out[1,], out[2,])
```

However, even for this example (which compares finally only the words einkaufen and wetter), I get a cosine similarity of 0.51, even though the words are not related at all.

Similarly, it happens for all kind of documents. When comparing German and English documents, the value is around 0.6. Isn't that really high? If both documents are german and do share some content, the value mostly excedes 0.9.

Now I am trying to figure out why the values are always that high. I am aware that my code probably is really weak, as I am still a beginner. However, I really appreciate any comments and suggestions to unterstand the problem here and to improve my textmining skills.

Thank you :)

Comment: I'm know word-embeddings, but not R. From docs for `tinyTextR`'s `Doc2Vec$new()` (<https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/textTinyR/versions/1.1.3/topics/Doc2Vec>), it doesn't appear to do anything like what `Doc2Vec` usually means. (It usually means: use the 'Paragraph Vectors' algorithm, similar to word2vec, to learn vectors for longer texts that *aren't* a simple combination of existing word-vectors.) So all I can do is warn: general word-embeddings/Doc2Vec experts may not be able to help much interpreting your setnence results – you may need expertise with that idiosyncratic library.

Comment: If I do use a lang (English) & vec-set (`GoogleNews` released in 2013) to compare `'weather'` and `'shopping'` – for example via online form at http://bionlp-www.utu.fi/wv_demo/ – I get a cos-sim of `0.178`, which is still more-similar than not, in the `-1.0` to `1.0` range of cos-sim. If your code were really just doing cos-sim for those 2 single words (& I'm not sure any using bizarro `Doc2Vec` is), & getting `0.51`, maybe R's `cosine()` only returns `[0.0-1.0]`-scaled results, or there's a difference with those vectors' training data wherein the word-vecs truly *are* more similar.

Comment: Thank you for your comment gojomo. I think the cosine()  function returns between 0.0 and 1.0. As you pointed out, the problem could lie in the training data but it could also be a result of my code. If there is no substantial error in the code, I still struggle with interpreting the results. One first takeaway for me is that I have to be careful, as the value depends on the training data and thus differs for different data sets.